# How to prevent firefox from opening a file over an existing browser window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox

If you drag and drop any file from your explorer into an existing Firefox tab, it will open the file in the same tab and thereby close the old tab. Is there any way of preventing this from happening? Producing a warning before the tab is closed would be even better. I already took a look into the about:config but could not find a solution.

Comment: Do you mean disable drop generally, or make it start a new tab?

Comment: I just want to prevent my existing tab from getting closed. So either not allowing files to be dropped inside firefox would be fine, or better: force firefox to open the file in a NEW tab.

Comment: I don't have the time to test, only to give some pointers, so you will need to do the rest. This would require some knowledge of JavaScript and using the Geasemonkey add-on.

Comment: I do not know JavaScript, so i will have to pass on your offer for now. Thanks anyway for your help! I will continue seraching for another solution to my problem.